# Group by year and month but only present the month and year actual mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table.

```
select * from `consumo`;
```

Outputs:

```
+----+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | cedula     | registroConsumo | fecha-hora          |
+----+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0931111111 |              20 | 2016-08-17 13:52:48 |
|  2 | 0931111111 |              25 | 2016-08-17 13:53:01 |
|  3 | 0311111111 |              27 | 2016-08-17 13:54:23 |
|  4 | 0311111111 |              10 | 2016-08-17 13:54:26 |
|  5 | 0311111111 |              12 | 2016-08-17 13:54:29 |
|  6 | 0311111111 |              14 | 2016-08-17 13:54:34 |
|  7 | 0311111111 |              19 | 2016-08-17 13:54:38 |
|  8 | 0311111111 |             190 | 2016-08-17 13:54:44 |
|  9 | 0311111111 |             195 | 2016-08-17 13:54:48 |
| 10 | 0912223333 |              19 | 2016-08-17 13:54:54 |
| 11 | 0111111111 |              20 | 2016-08-17 13:54:59 |
| 12 | 0111111111 |              23 | 2016-08-17 13:55:03 |
| 13 | 0111111111 |              27 | 2016-08-17 13:55:07 |
| 14 | 0111111111 |              35 | 2016-08-17 13:55:11 |
| 15 | 0111111111 |              10 | 2016-08-17 13:55:14 |
| 16 | 0111111111 |              35 | 2016-09-04 12:10:01 |
| 17 | 0111111111 |             330 | 2016-09-04 12:10:06 |
+----+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to group by year and month but only present the result of month and year actual all is in Mysql.

I did this:

```
select SUM(`registroConsumo`) from `consumo` 
GROUP BY YEAR(`fecha-hora`),MONTH(`fecha-hora`) 
HAVING YEAR(`fecha-hora`) = SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (SELECT NOW()))
AND    MONTH(`fecha-hora`) = SELECT EXTRACT (MONTH FROM (SELECT NOW())) ;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `` SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (SELECT NOW())) AND MONTH(`fecha-hora`) = SELECT EXTRA `` at line 1

Comment: What was your result? Please post any errors, and the full MySQL or PHP code.

Comment: In the interests of sanity, please don't use  '-' within table/column identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several missing parentheses in the sub-queries that appear in the `having` clause.

But you could approach this more pragmatically, and just return the most recent data you get, with the use of `order by` and `limit`:

```
select   YEAR(`fecha-hora`),
         MONTH(`fecha-hora`)
         SUM(`registroConsumo`) 
from     `consumo` 
group by YEAR(`fecha-hora`),
         MONTH(`fecha-hora`)
order by YEAR(`fecha-hora`) DESC,
         MONTH(`fecha-hora`) DESC
limit 1
```

Or, if it really has to match with the current year and month:

```
select   YEAR(`fecha-hora`),
         MONTH(`fecha-hora`)
         SUM(`registroConsumo`) 
from     `consumo` 
where    YEAR(`fecha-hora`) = YEAR(NOW())
and      MONTH(`fecha-hora`) = MONTH(NOW())
group by YEAR(`fecha-hora`),
         MONTH(`fecha-hora`)
```

Comment: I got this error,                                                                                                mysql> SELECT YEAR(`fecha-hora`), MONTH(`fecha-hora`), SUM(`registroConsumo`) FR
OM `consumo` GROUP BY YEAR(`fecha-hora`), MONTH(`fecha-hora`) HAVING YEAR(`fecha
-hora`) = YEAR(NOW()) and MONTH(`fecha-hora`) = MONTH(NOW());
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'fecha-hora' in 'having clause'

Comment: Sorry, I correct that. It should be a `where`, not a `having`. See update.